# Why can't I get the Text component of an Input Field

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

I have a TextMeshPro Input Field but my various attempts at getting the Text component are producing null reference exceptions. The Input Field is called Name. I reference this object when the player clicks OK after submitting their name.
Here is the GetName script:

```
public class GetName : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject Name;

    // These two are left over from previous attempts.
    public TextMeshProUGUI player_name;
    public TMP_InputField player_inputField;

    private string monicker;

    // Integer function should be less bother than a bool when called from another script.

    public int IsNameEmpty()
    {
        monicker = Name.GetComponent<TMP_InputField>().text.ToString();

    // Program never gets this far.
```

The OK function in the other script is:

```
public class WelcomeButtons : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GetName getName;

    void TaskOnClick6()
    {
        Debug.Log("You have clicked the OK button!");

        int isName = getName.IsNameEmpty(); // Causes null reference exception.

        // Program never gets this far.
```

Comment: Hi Pezza. Since I don't see that your GameObject Name is set within your code, are you sure that you referenced the GameObject containing your TMP_InputField to it? On the other hand, if you attached your GetName-Component to the GameObject containing the TMP_InputField, you could change "Name.GetComponent<TMP_InputField>().text.ToString();" to "GetComponent<TMP_InputField>().text.ToString();".

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The GetName script is attached to an empty GameObject, named NameControl. Should it be attached to the Input Field instead?

Answer (score 0):

A simple method to get the text from the input field

```
public class GetName: MonoBehaviour
{
public TMP_InputField name;

public void TaskOnClick()
{
    if(name =="")
    {
     Debug.log("NO Name Found");
    }
    else
    {
    Debug.log("NAME: "+name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the OK button's OnClick() approach?

Comment: give TaskOnClick() for the okay function

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion JOYSON S T. Just letting you know that the code as shown is in error: Assets\Scripts\GetName.cs(16,13): error CS0019: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'TMP_InputField' and 'string'.

Comment: instead of `""` give `null`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you attached the script above to an empty GameObject, then your script is missing the Link to the GameObject containing the TMP_InputField-Component. You can fix this in two simple ways, just decide what fits best for you:

a) Attach the GetName-script to the same GameObject that also contains the TMP_InputField-Component. Replace the Line "Name.GetComponent<TMP_InputField>().text.ToString();" with "GetComponent<TMP_InputField>().text.ToString();".

b) Leave the GetName-script on the empty GameObject. Make the "GameObject Name;" line public by changing it to "public GameObject Name". Go to the Unity-Editor. When selecting the GameObject containing the GetName-script, you should see the Name-Property and an empty Field next to it in the Inspector. Drag&Drop the GameObject containing the TMP_InputField-Component into it.

So, why did your code not work before? Well, the GetName-script needs some kind of reference to your TMP_InputField-component, which was missing. You tried this by getting it from the Name-Property, but never assigned it any value.

Comment: You were right. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the advice I've received. I now have a working version using the OnClick() approach:

```
public class GetName : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TMP_InputField user_inputField;      // User-entered name.

    public void SaveName()
    {
        Globals.player = user_inputField.text.ToString(); // Saved for later.
        Debug.Log("Globals.player is " + Globals.player);
    }

    public void ResetName()
    {
        user_inputField.text = "";
        Globals.player = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just two lines will work :

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
```

and

```
 public  TMPro.TMP_InputField Name;
```